# How can I find a suggested route between two geo points in osmdroid?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have downloaded a map from Open Street Map.
That file is an XML file that has the .osm extension.

I would like to know if there is any method in osmdroid that calculates
the distance between two points in the map, based on the map.osm file.

Is there any method in osmdroid that finds suggested routes between
two geo points?

e.g.

```
point1 (lat1,lon1);
point2 (lat2,lon2);

//method
SuggestedRoutes(point1,point2,[car|pedestrian|bicycle],map.osm);
```

Is there any method in osmdroid for that?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSMDroid isn't able to do routing processing and AFAIK no offline rendering, so you can't work with this framework and .OSM files. What you might do is to invoke an OSM based [online routing service](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/OnlineRouters) and use [osmDroid bonus pack](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/) to display this route.